# A question about floor functions, exponents, and congruence classes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $i, j, v, c, r, t$ be integers where:

- $i < j$
- $v > 0$
- $c \ge 0$
- $r > 1$
- $t > 1$
- $r \nmid t$

Does there always exist an integer $w$ where:

- $u = \left\lfloor\dfrac{t^{wv+c}}{r}\right\rfloor$
- For each prime $p | t$:

  > - $u \not\equiv i \pmod p$
  > - $u \not\equiv j \pmod p$

I am thinking that since there is an infinite number of $w$, eventually there will exist a $w$ where $u$ has the desired properties.

Is this straight forward to show whether it is true or false?  Does this turn out to be a question that is very difficult to resolve?

---

Edit:  Added property where $r \nmid t$ and changed to $r > 1$.

Comment: Do we have $r \nmid t$ ?

Comment: Great question.  Yes, let’s assume that otherwise the floor function isn’t needed.

Comment: my main problem is how to deal with the fractional part of the division otherwise $u= {t^{wv+c}\over r} -\left [{t^{wv+c}\over r }\right ]$ in normal arithmetic. where $\left [ x \right ]$ is the fractional part of $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false.

Take $$i=0,\ \ j=1,\ \ v=1,\ \ c=0,\ \ r=2,\ \ t=3$$

For $w\le 0$, we get
$$\left\lfloor\dfrac{3^{w}}{2}\right\rfloor\equiv 0\pmod 3$$

For $w\gt 0$,
$$\left\lfloor\dfrac{3^{w}}{2}\right\rfloor=m\ \ (m\in\mathbb Z)$$
is equivalent to
$$2m\le 3^w\lt 2m+2$$
from which
$$3^w=2m+1\implies \left\lfloor\dfrac{3^{w}}{2}\right\rfloor=m\equiv 1\pmod 3$$
follows.

It follows that there is no integer $w$ such that
$$\left\lfloor\dfrac{3^{w}}{2}\right\rfloor\equiv 2\pmod 3$$